# A query regarding the logic of the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I must be misunderstanding something regarding the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment because naively it would seem to lead to a possibly contradictory outcome. If I understand the basic experiment, we have two photons entangled such that you know the total quantum state of photon 1 and 2 combined. Thus by measuring one, you know the state of the other. Photon 1 will pass through both optical paths and interfere with itself if you do not measure the state of its entangled partner, photon 2. If however, you do measure the state of photon 2, then photon 1 pass though a single optical path, and will no longer interfere with itself. In the delayed choice, you make the path of photon 2 long enough so that photon 1 must have already passed through to both optical paths or not by the time photon 2 has been measured. Hence a decision in the future appears to effect the past of photon 1.

My question is the following:
Is it in principle possible to make the path of entangled partner photon 2 even longer, so that the interference pattern itself (or lack of) has occurred before the state of photon 2 has been measured? If this were possible than you might, in principle, decide to change your future decision to try to "trick" quantum mechanics by "changing" your future decision to measure the state of photon 2 (or not) so as to contradict original interference pattern of photon 1 (or lack of).

I suspect that the answer is no, because the presence (or not) of the interference pattern of photon 1 is itself a measurement of photon 1's quantum state, and thus photon 2's state must now be known. Is this the way out of the possible logic contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532849/delayed-choice-quantum-eraser-for-communication/532867#532867) , but the basic mistake is that when you have entangled particles you never see an interference pattern, regardless of how far and when you measure photon 2.  The interference pattern only shows when you select the  subgroup of photons 2 whose which path information is not available. Once you select only  the photons 1 from the original  pattern that correspond to those photons 2, then the interference pattern appears. But for that you need to send classical information back to the first detector.